# eyed3 file from bytes

Tags: python, eyed3, bytesio

Is it possible to modify the tags of a downloaded MP3, without writing it to the disk?

I am using

```
def downloadTrack(url)
    track_data = requests.get(url)

    audiofile = Mp3AudioInherited(track_data.content)
    audiofile.initTag()
```

with the class `Mp3AudioInherited` inherited from [core.AudioFile](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/_modules/eyed3/core.html#AudioFile) much like [mp3.Mp3AudioFile](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/_modules/eyed3/mp3.html#Mp3AudioFile). The only signficant difference:

```
class Mp3AudioInherited(core.AudioFile):
    ...
    def _read(self):        
        with io.BytesIO(self.data) as file_obj:
            self._tag = id3.Tag()
            tag_found = self._tag.parse(file_obj, self._tag_version)
            ...
```

Unfortunately `_tag.parse()` throws a `ValueError: Invalid type: <type '_io.BytesIO'>`. Isn't `BytesIO` a file-like object?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `io.BytesIO` objects are not file-like (i.e., they are not interchangeable with `file` objects) in Python 2. Try using [StringIO.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to get a memory-backed file-like object in Python 2.

Comment: Unfortunately `_tag.parse()` doesn't take something of `<type 'instance'>` either. Why is `StringIO.StringIO()` of type _'instance'_ and `io.BytesIO` _'_io.BytesIO'_ anyway?

Comment: It sounds like `_tag.parse()` is calling [type()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) on an object passed in to it and then raising a `ValueError` if it doesn't like the result. What you're seeing is the `repr()` of the Python type object that comes back from that call; but it's a bit tough to explain _why_ those type objects have the representations they do in the 500 characters of a StackOverflow comment.

Comment: Indeed. I probably wouldn't comprehend anyway. Do have an idea for a workaround nevertheless?

Comment: Not really, I haven't played with eyed3 before. Now might be a good time to consider how strong a reason you have to avoid hitting the filesystem, and whether you can use an ordinary file to achieve your goal.

Comment: Very true! I just thought that, perhaps, I am one line of code away from a solution. Given the size of this application, keeping it in memory would be more of a psychological thing anyway. Thank you for your quick guidance!